# How to get a value from edittext dynamically?

Tags: java, android, dynamic, android-edittext

I have tried searching unsucessfully. I need to have an edittext always checking if its value is changing and if it contains something do something. I have looked at a OnTouch listener but it is just checking if it is "touched" correct?

Illustrated through code:

```
EditText a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.MyID);
String check = a.getText().toString();
if(check.contains(" my String "))
{`//do something}
else{//keep checking until it contains specified string}
```

An example would be an "automatic calculate" button

ANSWER = 
This works in your OnCreate method. Thanks everyone or point me to TextWatcher()

```
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){
                if(myEditText.getText().toString().equals(" my String")){
                    //do something

        }

                }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,int start,int count, int after){} 
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

         }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) and call [addTextChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) on your EditText instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html). Create a class like this in your `Activity`

```
private class TempWatcher implements TextWatcher {

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
{   
     if (s.length() > 0) 
     {
          if(s.contains(" my String "))
           {`//do something}
     }
}
```

and attach a `TextWatcher` to your `EditText` like this after you initialize your `EditText`

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TempWatcher());
```

Then every time your text changes, this listener will check the values. You don't even need an `else` with this because it will just keep checking when the text changes

Comment: Great answer it works but I need to do something in my oncreate method. I thought about returning a boolean but that wont work because one is implementing textwatcher

Comment: I don't understand. What do you need to do in your `onCreate()`? Where do you want to return a boolean value?

Comment: My project involves parsing the String and I need to create spinner values from that String if it contains "my String"

Comment: Well, you obviously can't create the `Spinner` with the `String` that hasn't been created yet so you can populate the `Spinner` once your `String` equals what it needs to be. Other than that you need to give more explanation as to what you want or post a new question with the updated code a precise description of what you want.

Comment: Here is an outline:
Get string from EditText;

If it contains "my String" parse it; 

then add individual characteristics to an ArrayList <String> adapter;

My problem is that the TextWatcher doesn't return a value. If it returned a boolean then I could add characteristics to the adapter if it is true or else do nothing

Comment: Do you want to get a String at a certain point in time or watch what it equals? If the first then, `if my editText.contains("myString")`

Comment: Exactly. I need to get the String dynamically and if it contains a certain value I need to do something in my OnCreate Method to modify existing instance fields.

Comment: Ok, well if it doesn't contain the value when the `Activity` is created then you can't do something. You can use my answer and call a function to do something when it does equal that value

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a TextWatcher Here is how you can implement it:

```
    a.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(s.contains(" my String ")){
                //dosomething
             }
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```